# Simplify multiple rowwise computations

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that has basic descriptive statistics (Sum, Average, Max, and Count) about the quantity and bookings recorded for a particular product in a period. The product could be a new or old product.

The notation I am using to represent columns in my example is as follows:

**Notation:**

```
N and O = New and Old respectively
P1 and P2 = Period 1 and Period2 respectively
B and Q = Bookings and Quantity respectively
S and A = Sum and Average respectively.
P1 = Period 1
P2 = Period 2
P12 = Period 1 + Period 2 = Total Period
n = count 
M = Max
```

Therefore, N_P2_B_A would mean **N**ew products (N) sold in **P**eriod **2**(**P2**) and compute **B**ookings (B) **A**verage(A). Similarly, P12_Q_A would mean **A**verage (A) **Q**uantity (Q) sold in Total **P**eriod (P12).

I have done this to shorten the column names and minimize the burden of remembering them. Auto-complete doesn't work well with column names in RStudio.

**What I am trying to do:**
The objective of my code is to compute `Comparison_p1_p2` wherein I would add the output from the following four logic. For each of them, the answer would be `TRUE` if yes, and `FALSE` if no.

a) Is Bookings Average in P2 > Bookings Average in P1 + P2 (i.e. total period);

b) Is Quantity Average in P2 > Bookings Average in P1 + P2 (i.e. total period)

c) Is Max Bookings in P2 > Bookings Average in P1 + P2 (i.e. total period)

d) Is Max Quantity in P2 > Quantity Average in P1 + P2 (i.e. total period)

Similarly, I would do the comparison of new and old products sold in P2. I would call this column `Comparison_p2new_P2old`. I would add the output of the following:

a) Is Bookings average from selling new products in P2 > Bookings average from selling old products in P2?

b) Is Quantity average from selling new products in P2 > Quantity average from selling old products in P2?

**Where do I need your help**
Now, I need help with simplifying this code. While my code works, I am not sure how I can simplify it by using vectorized operations. I have recently transitioned from C++/Java so using R's vectorization is really tough for me.

**Input file:**

```
dput(Master_Final)
structure(list(Country_SL6 = c("United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom"
), Company.Name = c("Mass Incorp.", "Mass Incorp.", "Mass Incorp.", 
"Mass Incorp.", "Texan Incorp.", "Texan Incorp."), Family_Type = c("N", 
"N", "O", "O", "O", "O"), Ship_Period = c("P1", "P2", "P1", "P2", 
"P1", "P2"), Q_S = c(1, 15, 4633, 57317, 251, 1205), B_S = c(1157, 
26958.4, 3736290.43, 6144393.02, 171699, 1022155.1), Q_A = c(1, 
2.14285714285714, 71.2769230769231, 707.617283950617, 25.1, 34.4285714285714
), B_A = c(1157, 3851.2, 57481.3912307692, 75856.7039506173, 
17169.9, 29204.4314285714), Q_M = c(1, 8, 1940, 11000, 234, 617
), B_M = c(1157, 17980, 1270354, 1463415.25, 128258, 341293.55
), n = c(1, 7, 65, 81, 10, 35)), .Names = c("Country_SL6", "Company.Name", 
"Family_Type", "Ship_Period", "Q_S", "B_S", "Q_A", "B_A", "Q_M", 
"B_M", "n"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Sample Output:**
Alternatively, you could run my code below to generate sample output.

```
dput(Top_Act_Final)
structure(list(Country_SL6 = c("United Kingdom", "United States"
), Company.Name = c("Texan Incorp.", "Mass Incorp."), Comparison_p1_p2 = c(4L, 
4L), Comparison_p2new_P2old = c(NA, 0L)), class = c("rowwise_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .Names = c("Country_SL6", 
"Company.Name", "Comparison_p1_p2", "Comparison_p2new_P2old"))
```

**Code:**

```
Top_Act_Final<- Master_Final %>%
  #Spread out the columns so that we can do row-wise operations
  gather(key = Column, value = value,Q_S:n) %>%
  unite(P_Column, Ship_Period,Column,sep="_") %>%
  unite(F_P_Column, Family_Type,P_Column,sep="_") %>%
  spread(F_P_Column, value) %>%
  dplyr::rowwise(.)%>%
  #Notation:
  #N vs. O = New or Old
  #P1 vs. P2 = Period 1 vs. Period2
  #B vs. Q = Bookings vs. Quantity
  #S vs. A = Sum vs. Average

  dplyr::mutate(P12_B_S = sum(N_P1_B_S,O_P1_B_S,N_P2_B_S,O_P2_B_S,na.rm=TRUE),
                P12_Q_S = sum(N_P1_Q_S,O_P1_Q_S,N_P2_Q_S,O_P2_Q_S,na.rm=TRUE),
                P12_B_A = sum(N_P1_B_A*N_P1_n,  O_P1_B_A*O_P1_n,  N_P2_B_A*N_P2_n,  O_P2_B_A*O_P2_n,  na.rm = TRUE)/sum(N_P1_n,O_P1_n,N_P2_n,O_P2_n,na.rm=TRUE),
                P12_Q_A = sum(N_P1_B_A*N_P1_n,  O_P1_B_A*O_P1_n,  N_P2_B_A*N_P2_n,  O_P2_B_A*O_P2_n,  na.rm = TRUE)/sum(N_P1_n,O_P1_n,N_P2_n,O_P2_n,na.rm=TRUE),

                P2_B_A = sum(N_P2_B_A*N_P2_n,  O_P2_B_A*O_P2_n,  na.rm = TRUE)/sum(N_P2_n, O_P2_n,na.rm=TRUE),
                P2_Q_A = sum( N_P2_Q_A*N_P2_n,  O_P2_Q_A*O_P2_n,  na.rm = TRUE)/sum(N_P2_n, O_P2_n,na.rm=TRUE),
                P1_B_A = sum(N_P1_B_A*N_P1_n,  O_P1_B_A*O_P1_n,  na.rm = TRUE)/sum(N_P1_n, O_P1_n,na.rm=TRUE),
                P1_Q_A = sum( N_P1_Q_A*N_P1_n,  O_P1_Q_A*O_P1_n,  na.rm = TRUE)/sum(N_P1_n, O_P1_n,na.rm=TRUE),
                P1_B_S = sum(N_P1_B_S,  O_P1_B_S,  na.rm = TRUE),                  
                P1_Q_S = sum(N_P1_Q_S,  O_P1_Q_S,  na.rm = TRUE),                  

                P2_B_S = sum(N_P2_B_S,  O_P2_B_S,  na.rm = TRUE),                  
                P2_Q_S = sum(N_P2_Q_S,  O_P2_Q_S,  na.rm = TRUE),      

                P2_B_M = max(N_P2_B_M,O_P2_B_M, na.rm = TRUE),
                P2_Q_M = max(N_P2_Q_M,O_P2_Q_M, na.rm = TRUE),
                P1_n = sum(N_P1_n,O_P1_n,na.rm = TRUE),
                P2_n = sum(N_P2_n,O_P2_n,na.rm = TRUE))

#replace NaN or -Inf with NA
Top_Act_Final[is.nan(Top_Act_Final$P2_B_A),"P2_B_A"]<-NA
Top_Act_Final[is.nan(Top_Act_Final$P2_Q_A),"P2_Q_A"]<-NA
Top_Act_Final[is.nan(Top_Act_Final$P2_B_M),"P2_B_M"]<-NA
Top_Act_Final[is.nan(Top_Act_Final$P2_Q_M),"P2_Q_M"]<-NA

Top_Act_Final<-     Top_Act_Final %>%

  dplyr::mutate(P12_B_A =sum(P1_B_A*P1_n,P2_B_A*P2_n,na.rm=TRUE)/(P1_n+P2_n),
                P12_Q_A =sum(P1_Q_A*P1_n,P2_Q_A*P2_n,na.rm=TRUE)/(P1_n+P2_n),
                P12_B_S =sum(P1_B_S,P2_B_S,na.rm=TRUE),
                P12_Q_S =sum(P2_Q_S,P1_Q_S,na.rm=TRUE)) %>%

  dplyr::mutate(B_A_c = P2_B_A>P12_B_A,
                Q_A_c = P2_Q_A>P12_Q_A,
                B_M_c = P2_B_M>P12_B_A,
                Q_M_c = P2_Q_M>P12_Q_A,
                N_O_A_c = N_P2_B_A>O_P2_B_A,
                N_O_S_c = N_P2_B_S>O_P2_B_S) %>%

  dplyr::mutate(Comparison_p1_p2 = sum(B_A_c, Q_A_c, B_M_c, Q_M_c, na.rm = TRUE),
                Comparison_p2new_P2old = sum(N_O_A_c,N_O_S_c)) %>%

  dplyr::select(Country_SL6, Company.Name, Comparison_p1_p2, Comparison_p2new_P2old)
```

Sorry for the long post, but I wanted to be as detailed as possible. Is there anyway we can shorten my code?

I wrote this code last week, and while reviewing it today (to re-use it), I had a tough time. I'd truly appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly, but is there a chance your code could be more simple by keeping your data in a "long" format? E.g. in a form like `[Country, Company, Family (New/Old), Period (P1/P2), Type (Quantity/Booking), Statistic (Sum/Average/Max), ..]`

Comment: @Alexis_laz - Thanks, but do you mind posting the solution using long format? At the end of the day, format doesn't matter---anything that makes my code simpler is best. Moreover, I have posted full working solution above. Plus, you haven't really specified what's not clear. I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: I started on this, but am not clear on what your output columns are -- you listed four comparisons you want to calculate, but somehow come down to two result columns, neither of which maps to your requested columns.

Comment: @Mark - Thanks for your help. Output columns are `Country_SL6`, `Company.Name`,`Comparison_p1_p2`,`Comparsion_p2new_p2old`. The 2nd last column was generated by doing row-wise sum of logical vectors `B_A_c` (aka Booking Avg Comparison), `Q_A_c` (aka Quantity Avg Comparison), `B_M_c` (aka Max Booking comparison), and `Q_M_c` (Max Quantity comparison). Hence, the range for this column would be from 0 to 4. Similarly, last col was generated by adding `N_O_A_c` (aka new old booking avg comparison) and `N_O_S_c` (aka new old booking sum comparison). `Top_Act_Final` represents this. Does that help?

Comment: Also, Mark...if you could run the script I have posted above, `Top_Act_Final` would show you the expected output. I look forward to hearing from you. I am dying for help on this topic. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @watchtower : I am talking about a format like `master2 = reshape(Master_Final, direction = "long", varying = 5:10, sep = "_", timevar = "Statistic")[-9]`. And you can obtain some basic summaries as simple as, say, `aggregate(cbind(n, B, Q) ~ Country_SL6 + Company.Name + Ship_Period + Statistic, master2, sum, subset = Statistic %in% c("A", "M"))`. Your approach can only lead to hardcoding and I, really, suggest to change the format and operate on the "apply by group" framework.

Comment: @watchtower : I believe focusing/asking on (i) how to reshape appropriately and, (ii) how to apply an operation by group(s) will reveal a more natural/convenient way to solve such tasks.

Comment: @alexis - Thanks for your wonderful insights. However, it has been only a few months since I have started using R. So, my knowledge about R is very limited. I'd appreciate if you could post a working example that I can use. I have posted the source data and would really appreciate your help. Also, I get goosebumps every time I have to use this code because of the reasons you have mentioned. Other than hardcoding I don't know what else to do. I don't have any resource other than SO who could guide me. I am really stuck.

Comment: @watchtower : continuing from my above comment (that contains `master2`): `master3 = reshape(master2, direction = "long", varying = list(7:8), timevar = "BQtype", v.names = "val", times = names(master2)[7:8])[-9]; master4 = reshape(master3, direction = "wide", timevar = "Statistic", v.names = "val", idvar = c("Country_SL6", "Company.Name", "Family_Type", "Ship_Period", "BQtype"))`. I believe `master4` is suitable to work with.  There, certainly, exists a better way to transform your data, probably with `dplyr`, though I'm not familiar at all, hence the ugly code with multiple `reshape`s.

Comment: (...cont) And, then, you can compute your summaries like `tmp1 = master4 %>% group_by(Country_SL6, Company.Name, Ship_Period, BQtype) %>% summarize(A = sum(val.A * n) / sum(n), S = sum(val.S), n = sum(n))`. To get the totals for P1 & P2, you ca use something like `tmp1 %>% group_by(Country_SL6, Company.Name, BQtype) %>% summarize(A = sum(A * n) / sum(n), S = sum(S))`. Note, that the present dplyr code might not idiomatic so I'd suggest you consult better dplyr users.

Comment: @alexis- First off, thanks for your insights. However, (it will be great if you could correct me) I believe that `Master_Final` (the one that I have posted) is very similar to `Master4` except that you have converted columns by `Q` and `B`. Isn't it? Hence, there are 12 rows instead of 6. What do you think? Also, you mentioned that I could consult other `dplyr` users. How do I do this on StackOverflow? I'm curious.

Comment: @watchtower : You 're right about "Master_Final" and "master4" - I just wanted to pass through "master3" which is the "longest" format and the most convenient to manipulate as needed. For the operations I could come across in your code, I had my starting point from "master3" (i.e. the format I consider the most flexible to manipulate) and ended with "master4" to compute your variables. If you can find a format for your data that you feel comfortable, just post another Q, here, on how to compute your summary statistics per country/type/etc.